# Can't figure out how htaccess works with strings of URL and Parameters?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Totally don't know about htaccess...

I want to redirect this:

some_domain_url/some_parameters

to:

some_domain_url/index.php/some_parametes.

Tryied a lot of redirection rules but nothing happened.

Only got 404.

I assume that *some_parameters* can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yes!! So what is happening is RewriteBase / means that everything after / is considered a REQUESTED_FILENAME? What ! stands for?

Comment: `RewriteBase /` is optional here. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means request is not for a directory and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means request is not for a file.